# Comparing two associated arrays and updating one based on the comparison

Tags: php

So I have a couple of associated arrays of equal length and associations, and need to compare them. If the voted key in the first array has a value, I need to update the voted key value in the second array with that same value.

```
// create the arrays...
$votes_array = [];
array_push($votes_array, array(
    'id' => '1',
    'voted' => '-1'
    )
);
array_push($votes_array, array(
    'id' => '1',
    'voted' => ''
    )
);


$menu_array = [];
array_push($menu_array, array(
    'id' => '1',
    'voted' => ''
    )
);
array_push($menu_array, array(
    'id' => '1',
    'voted' => ''
    )
);
```

I tried this but but couldn't even get the result to echo true.

```
foreach ($votes_array as $votes_array_key => $votes_array_value) {
    foreach ($menu_array as $menu_array_key => $menu_array_value) {
        if( $votes_array_key == 'voted' && ($votes_array_value == '1' || $votes_array_value == '-1') ){
            echo 'true';
            // Update the $menu_array array index with the associated 'voted' value. 
        }
    }
}
```

So it would end up with $menu_array[0]['voted'] being '-1'.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I've also modified the accepted answer to cater for when the length of votes_array varies.

```
foreach($votes_array as $votes_key => $votes_vote) {
    if( ! $votes_vote['voted'] ) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        $getVoteId = $votes_array[$votes_key]['id'];
        foreach($menu_array as $menu_key => $menu_vote) 
        {
            if($menu_array[$menu_key]['id'] == $getVoteId)
            $menu_array[$menu_key]['voted'] = $votes_vote['voted'];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Add a condition `if value == ""`. Code looks fine, I think that there is no `voted=1` in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are strings and arrays are equal in length like you said this would be simple one from top of the head:

```
foreach($votes_array as $key => $vote) {
        if( ! $vote['voted']) continue;
        $menu_array[$key]['voted'] = $vote['voted'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The vote array is actually variable (0-4 elements), whereas the menu array has mostly 4 elements (both always have the same associations), but this can sometimes be three. But I should be able to figure out how to modify this to get it to work for that too.

Comment: I've added the result to what I mentioned above as an edit. There is probably a more elegant way to do it, but there it is :P

Answer (score 1):

It seems you set your `voted` keys, so im using **empty** instead of **isset** to check for a non-value.

```
foreach($votes_array as $key=>$vote) {
   if (!empty($vote["voted"])) {
      $menu_array[$key]["voted"] = $vote["voted"];
   }
}
```